# Does .NET have a Dictionary implementation that is equivalent to Java's ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: .net, concurrency, dictionary

To recap for those .NET gurus who might not know the Java API:

[ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in Java has atomic methods (i.e. require no external locking) for common Map modification operations such as:

```
putIfAbsent(K key, V value)
remove(Object key, Object value)
replace(K key, V value)
```

It also allows iteration over the keyset without locking (it takes a copy at the start of iteration) and `get()` operations can generally be interleaved with calls to `put()` without blocking (it uses fine grained lock striping [IIRC](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IIRC)).

Anyway, my question is: **does .NET have an equivalent Dictionary implementation?**

I guess more generally, I'd be keen to know if .NET has a more general set of thread safe collection libraries.  Or concurrency utilities in general - equivalent to [Doug Lea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_Lea)'s `java.util.concurrent` libraries.

Comment: do you really need java tag here?

Comment: Georgy - you're right - it is a .net question, not a Java one.  Tag removed.

Comment: My project http://concurrent.codeplex.com/ has a Sharded dictionary, which allows multiple readers &  writers, and allows transactions on certain values. It's heavily in development though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. The closest thing to what you're looking for would probably be the Synchronized method of the Hashtable, which returns a (sort of) thread-safe wrapper around the hashtable. It's only thread-safe for multiple writers or multiple readers, though. If I recall correctly, a mixture of writers and readers will not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 16):

The incoming .Net 4.0 has a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(VS.100).aspx) class, it has a convenient [GetOrAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(VS.100).aspx) method.

```
public TValue GetOrAdd(
    TKey key,
    Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory
)
```

Very useful for global server caches.

Comment: for global server caches it might be better to use a `MemoryCache` object, otherwise you might leak memory if not manually removing the referenced objects from the `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: Beware the valueFactory for GetOrAdd can be executed multiple times and **is not atomic** as demonstrated [Here](http://ayende.com/blog/4802/concurrentdictionary-getoradd-may-call-the-valuefactory-method-more-than-once) and [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/17/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrentdictionary.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This was written prior to .NET 4 being released, when obviously there's `ConcurrentDictionary`. I'm leaving it here as a reference for those needing .NET 3.5.

I don't know of any equivalent to `ConcurrentHashMap`.

In terms of general concurrency utilities - .NET has always provided a bit more than the basics which Java used to provide, in terms of [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx), [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx), [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) and [`ReaderWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx); then more recently (.NET 2.0) [`Semaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) and (.NET 3.5) [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) - as well as the process-wide thread pool, of course.

A bigger shake-up will come in .NET 4.0 when Parallel Extensions arrives - that should make concurrency *much* simpler. Likewise the [Coordination and Concurrency Runtime](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL55/) is finally breaking free of the shackles of the Microsoft Robotics Studio, although I'm not clear on exactly where it's headed (whether it'll be part of .NET itself, or a separate library).

Comment: I was under the impression (from public MSDN blogs) that it was destined to be a core part of .NET 4.0 itself.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Jon.  Parallel Extensions looks very interesting.  Just to be clear - I am not trolling - this is not a "Java has better libraries than .net" rant.  Am just new to .net and keen to see what is available out of the box.

Comment: Marc: The CCR as part of .NET 4.0? Links would be welcome!

Serg: Don't worry, I didn't take it that way :)

Comment: @Jon: For being out of date but now that you've updated it I removed the downvote. :-)

Comment: @Jon Harrop: Thanks. In future it would be helpful if you commented when you downvoted, to make it clearer to the answerer what should be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find that having individual methods as synchronized generally isn't as useful as it sounds.

Commonly, you might want to do a related "get" and "put" in close succession, and if another thread is looking at the same values you have an immediate thread race. Likewise (depending on the scenario) you don't *want* somebody reading values that you are working on.

For a broad approach, simply using an external `Monitor` (`lock(...)` can work well for many situations. It is simple, light-weight, and unless you are under **heavy** thread load, more than adequate.

For more complex scenarios, things like `ReaderWriterLockSlim` etc are more flexible. But I'd start simple, and only change things if profiling shows there is a genuine contention issue.

As Jon notes, with Parallel Extension comes a a whole new slew of high performance synchronization devices; from what I can see (for example [here](http://www.betanews.com/article/Everyone_talk_at_once_NET_40_will_include_Parallel_Extensions/1223931673), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2008/10/10/8994927.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc817396.aspx)), this is part of .NET 4.0

Comment: In Java's ConcurrentHashMap, the individual get, replace, putIfAbsent, etc methods are not syncronised.  They use non blocking algorithms to work without locking under most load situations.

I'll take a look at ReaderWriterLockSlim - thanks for the tip.